# Nodejs firesbase firestore does not retrieve any data using admin sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read data from firestore database of firebase using admin sdk. The function returns nothing even I don't receive any error. The objective is to get the data using admin sdk and pass it to the browser using ejs variable.

Here is my code.

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require("path to json file");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "mydatabase id"
});

var db = admin.firestore();
var courses = db.collection("courses");


app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    var email = req.query.id;
    courses.where("email", "==", email).get().then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        res.render("public/main.ejs", {
            data: data
        })
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  var email = req.query.id;
  var coursesRef = admin.firestore().collection('courses');
  coursesRef.where("email", "==", email).get().then(function (data) {

    data.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data())
    });

      res.render("public/main.ejs", {
          data: data
      })
  }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
  })

});
```